# Detect in python which keys are pressed

Tags: python, events, keyboard

I need to know which key is being pressed right now. I'm not looking to capture some specific keys to trigger an event or anything like that,

I want to know which keys are pressed now and display a list of them.

I also need to capture special keys like F1 ... F12, shift, alt, home, windows, etc. Basically all keys on the keyboard.

How do I do this in python? How do I capture keyboard events?

#### Related

- [Cross platform keylogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365110/cross-platform-keylogger)
- [Is there a cross-platform python low-level API to capture or generate keyboard events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676713/is-there-a-cross-platform-python-low-level-api-to-capture-or-generate-keyboard-ev)

**EDIT**

Just so you know I'm not trying to make a keylogger. I'm trying to make a diagnoses tool (I split water on my laptop and the keyboard is starting to get crazy sometime!!)

Comment: [PyKeylogger](https://sourceforge.net/p/pykeylogger/wiki/Main_Page/) mentioned in [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365110/cross-platform-keylogger/365225#365225) might do the job.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do something like this, if you're not too fussy, is to bring in a GUI toolkit such as pygame or wxPython.  For example, run the wxPython Demo, then go to the demo for KeyEvents.

Answer (score 0):

(from the pynput documentation)

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

This code from the pynput documentation seems to work. I'm not sure how to get it as a variable but it will print out keys in the terminal.