# Scanning Keypress in Python

Tags: python, linux, scripting

I have paused a script for lets say 3500 seconds by using time module for ex time.sleep(3500).

Now, my aim is to scan for keypresses while the script is on sleep, i mean its on this line.

Its like I want to restart the script if a **"keypress Ctrl+R"** is pressed.

For ex.. consider

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
print "Hello.. again"
while True:
     time.sleep(3500)
```

Now while the code is at last line, If i press Ctrl+R, i want to re-print "Hello.. again" line.

Comment: You may want to look into how this website works. So far you have not cast a single vote, nor accepted a single answer. That is bad form.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694296/detect-in-python-which-keys-are-pressed

Comment: sorry.. Am very new to this forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am aware that this does not fully answer your question, but you could do the following:

1. Put the program logic code in a function, say `perform_actions`. Call it when the program starts.
2. After the code has been run, start listening for an [interrupt](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt).

   - That is, the user must press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>.
3. On receiving an interrupt, wait half a second; if <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is pressed again, then exit.
4. Otherwise, restart the code.

Thus one interrupt behaves as you want <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to behave. Two quick interrupts quit the program.

```
import time

def perform_actions():
    print("Hello.. again")

try:
    while True:
        perform_actions()
        try:
            while True: time.sleep(3600)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            time.sleep(0.5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

A nice side-effect of using a signal (in this case `SIGINT`) is that you also restart the script through other means, e.g. by running `kill -int <pid>`.

Comment: A solution with ctrl+r would have been nicer ;)

Comment: ya.. this is also not bad. I mean it solves my problem for now. But, i wanna know how can I use this with any other combination...
If anyone knows, pls continue to reply..

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use Tkinter {needs X :(}

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Tkinter import * # needs python-tk

root = Tk()

def hello(*ignore):
    print 'Hello World'

root.bind('<Control-r>', hello)
root.mainloop() # starts an X widget
```

This script prints `Hello World` to the console if you press `ctrl+r`

See also [Tkinter keybindings](http://www.goingthewongway.com/195/tkinter-keyboard-bindings-in-python/). Another solution uses GTK can be found [here](https://www.siafoo.net/snippet/239)

Comment: Since Tkinker is not a standard module. I wish there was a different solution.

Comment: IFAIK There is no way binding keys without using an X or widget library. So you have to use qt, gtk or tkinter :) You may want to visit http://kaizer.se/wiki/python-keybinder/ which proposes a keybinding mechanism for python. But this isn't standard python also.

Answer (score -2):

in a for loop sleep 3500 times for 1 second checking if a key was pressed each time

```
# sleep for 3500 seconds unless ctrl+r is pressed
for i in range(3500):
    time.sleep(1)
    # check if ctrl+r is pressed
    # if pressed -> do something
    # otherwise go back to sleep
```

Comment: Why do i run the loop unnecessarily? How can we do it while program is in sleep state.