# Keystroke detection using Python

Tags: python

How is keystroke detection done using Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect in python which keys are pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694296/detect-in-python-which-keys-are-pressed)

Comment: Are you trying to detect system-wide keystrokes?

Answer (score 2):

[This old discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694296/detect-in-python-which-keys-are-pressed) in StackOverflow might helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what problem you are trying to solve. However, there is a Python FAQ (with a stock answer) that should have you on your way: [How do I get a single keypress at a time?](http://www.python.org/doc//current/faq/library.html#how-do-i-get-a-single-keypress-at-a-time).

Comment: The link is dead now.