# monitor keyboard events with python in windows 7

Tags: python, events, windows-7, event-handling

Is there any way to monitor keyboard events in windows 7 with python without the python program having focus? I would like to run the python script as a background process that monitors certain keyboard events and does certain things on various keyboard input combinations.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365110/cross-platform-keylogger  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694296/detect-in-python-which-keys-are-pressed

Comment: None of those address the python process running in the background.

Comment: I looked into pyhook and it refuses to install on windows 7 with python 2.7.

Comment: Have you tried "Backwards Compatibility Mode"?

Comment: I don't think it's a compatibility mode issue. PyHook just refuses to run because it says it requires python 2.6 even though the documentation says any version of python starting at 2.4 is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I got pyHook working after installing the 32bit version of python 2.7 and compiling pyHook from the source with MinGW. Thanks for the pointers everyone.