# How do I get key pressed?

Tags: python

I was wondering how do I get a key pressed in python

I tried doing:

```
import msvcrt as keys
while True:
    key = keys.getch()
    if key == "a":
        print("You have pressed a")
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: You didn't really say what your problem is.

Comment: This code works how I would expect.  How do you expect it to work?

Comment: What is this for? If you plan on more advanced console input/drawing/refreshing take a look at 'curses' library. Depending what you are doing, it might be easier to write in a non-console app, like pygame/pyglet even if you render mostly text. (Like a modern roguelike)

Comment: Take a look at PyHook.(Also possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501700/how-to-get-in-python-the-key-pressed-without-press-enter)

Comment: Check This Out http://www.ehow.com/how_12166842_key-presses-python.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you:

```
import msvcrt
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit() and msvcrt.getch() == chr(97): # chr(97) = 'a'
        print("You have pressed a")
```

Note: your code and my code won't work in many Python IDE's! You need to execute the python file, e.g. in a command window.

Comment: This is like the OP's code except it will take 100% CPU. And why write `chr(97)` when it is the same as `'a'`?

Comment: Looking back at this question years later, it seems to work fine. I mustn't have tried it in the console. Thanks for your help!