# How to break this loop in Python by detecting key press

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

```
from subprocess import call
try:
    while True:
        call (["raspivid -n -b 2666666.67 -t 5000 -o test.mp4"],shell=True)
        call (["raspivid -n -b 2666666.67 -t 5000 -o test1.mp4"],shell=True)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

I plan to make it breaking loop while I am pressing *any* button. However I tried lots of methods to break the and none of them worked.

Comment: Have you tried using `break`...?

Comment: the answer is in the Title

Comment: There's no way that this is the only portion of the code. A `KeyboardInterrupt` would trip the `except` and the program would continue after that, but since that's the end of the shown program, it would terminate.

Comment: @2rs2ts Thank you for answering me. This is the latest version of my code. I saw it on someone's blog. Anyway, these methods can only break the loop while I am pressing control+c. What I am trying to do is breaking the loop by pressing any buttons. By the way, as you see, my code aims to record the video again and again until I press a button. Is that possible to stop recording immediately after pressing?

Comment: Reading any arbitrary key input is not as straightforward in Python. You could try [this snippet](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892-getch-like-unbuffered-character-reading-from-stdin/) I found when googling for "python detect key press." It's up to you to find a solution for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want your code to be more like this:

```
from subprocess import call

while True:
    try:
        call(["raspivid -n -b 2666666.67 -t 5000 -o test.mp4"], shell=True)
        call(["raspivid -n -b 2666666.67 -t 5000 -o test1.mp4"], shell=True)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break  # The answer was in the question!
```

You [`break`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) a loop exactly how you would expect.

Comment: The `while` loop is local to the scope of the `try`, so this will produce a syntax error.

Comment: @2rs2ts Thank you very much, I failed to look at the way I would implement this and not just the keyword. Answer has been edited.

Comment: @AlexThomton Thank you for answering me. This is the latest version of my code. I saw it on someone's blog. Anyway, these methods can only break the loop while I am pressing control+c. What I am trying to do is breaking the loop by pressing any buttons. By the way, as you see, my code aims to record the video again and again until I press a button. Is that possible to stop recording immediately after pressing?

Comment: @VaFancy you can get any keypress by putting `if msvcrt.kbhit(): break` in your `while` loop instead of a `try`-`except` structure.

Comment: @AlexThomton Many thanks. But as far as I know 'msvcrt' can only work on windows. I need the method that can working on Raspberry PI, is there any?

Comment: @VaFancy In that case, on a UNIX based system such as that, use the `curses` module. However I'm afraid that's where my help ends, as I am a Windows user I know next to nothing about `curses` so you'll have to do some digging or ask a separate question.

Comment: @AlexThornton You have already helped me a lot and I appreciate it. I will try to find out how to solve this. BTW, it seems that I spelled your name incorrectly all the time.

Answer (score 4):

Use a different thread to listen for a "ch".

```
import sys
import thread
import tty
import termios
from time import sleep

breakNow = False

def getch():

    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)

    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)

    return ch

def waitForKeyPress():

    global breakNow

    while True:
        ch = getch()

        if ch == "b": # Or skip this check and just break
            breakNow = True
            break

thread.start_new_thread(waitForKeyPress, ())

print "That moment when I will break away!"

while breakNow == False:
    sys.stdout.write("Do it now!\r\n")
    sleep(1)

print "Finally!"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
try:
    while True:
        do_something()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Taken from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13181036/2317111)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from subprocess import call
    while True:
        try:
            call (["raspivid -n -b 2666666.67 -t 5000 -o test.mp4"],shell=True)
            call (["raspivid -n -b 2666666.67 -t 5000 -o test1.mp4"],shell=True)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
        except:
            break
```

Comment: Why add the extra `except`? Silent failures! Arrrgh! Also the `while` is unnecessarily indented.

Comment: @AdrianB Thank you for answering me. It works as same as using one except. Are there any methods that can break a loop by pressing any keys?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found with threads and standard libraries
Loop keeps going on until one key is pressed
Returns the key pressed as a single character string
Works in Python 2.7 and 3

```
import thread
import sys

def getch():
    import termios
    import sys, tty
    def _getch():
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(fd)
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch
    return _getch()

def input_thread(char):
    char.append(getch())

def do_stuff():
    char = []
    thread.start_new_thread(input_thread, (char,))
    i = 0
    while not char :
        i += 1

    print "i = " + str(i) + " char : " + str(char[0])

do_stuff()
```