# How to interrupt a python program?

Tags: python

I have made a program that essentially runs a loop like so:

```py
while(true):
    i = 0
    while(i < 60):
        i += 1
        time.sleep(1)
```

I would like to be able to pause it while it is running and go back to it (keeping the `i` as it was when interrupted) . Currently the program has nothing to do with taking an input from the user and it just runs in the background. Is there a way to pause a running script in a way that will keep the code at the same state that it was when I paused it and be able to continue from that point?
The program runs either on pycharm or normal Python 2.7 through the cmd.
(I have some basic knowledge of key logging and thread usage. So if that will work I am willing to try it out).

Comment: What platform are you running it on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to kill a while loop with a keystroke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180941/how-to-kill-a-while-loop-with-a-keystroke)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could catch a keyboard interrupt exception (how you'd normally end the program) and then wait until the user presses enter again. That'd be something like this

```py
while(true):
    i = 0
    while(i < 60):
        try:
            i += 1
            time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            input('Press enter to continue')
```

Comment: Though that would not keep your place in the inner loop for resuming

Comment: Oh right, the try/except should probably be inside that loop

Comment: a keyboard interrupt exception is ctr+z (eof)? because i would normally end the program by shutting down the pycharm debugger or the cmd window

Comment: Okay... I tried this out and it doesn't work all the way. I can interrupt the program by using ctrl + c but when i get back pressing the enter button the window writes back to me "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing"
plus , this does not work in the pycharm debugger for some reason

Comment: problem solved! the input function is bad and raw_input works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In *nix environment, simply press `Ctrl+Z`, process will be "paused" in background. To resume use commands: [`fg`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fg) in foreground, [`bg`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fg) in background. To see all [`jobs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/jobs).

There is no action required in python to work this on linux.