# What is the best way to keep a python loop running until stopped by the user?

Tags: python

In python, would the best way to keep a loop running until stopped by the user be as follows?

```
while not KeyboardInterrupt:

# The code I want repeated until I specify it to stop

break
```

I am new to code and would appreciate the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to kill a while loop with a keystroke?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180941/how-to-kill-a-while-loop-with-a-keystroke)

Answer (score 1):

[How to kill a while loop with a keystroke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180941/how-to-kill-a-while-loop-with-a-keystroke)

Taken from Keith's answer

```
try:
    while True:
        do_something()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

I suggest that you read up on exceptions and exception handling so you undertand what is different between the above and your posted code

Comment: There is no point in answering a duplicate with an answer that was in the dupe target.  You can instead, flag it as a duplicate and it will probably be closed with a link to the other question.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
//do your thing
```

This would help

Comment: How does the user stop the loop?