# graceful interrupt of while loop in ipython notebook

Tags: ipython, interrupt, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm running some data analysis in ipython notebook. A separate machine collects some data and saves them to a server folder, and my notebook scans this server periodically for new files, and analyzes them.

I do this in a while loop that checks every second for new files. Currently I have set it up to terminate when some number of new files are analyzed. However, I want to instead terminate upon a keypress.

I have tried try-catching a keyboard interrupt, as suggested here: [How to kill a while loop with a keystroke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180941/how-to-kill-a-while-loop-with-a-keystroke)

but it doesn't seem to work with ipython notebook (I am using Windows).

Using openCV's keywait does work for me, but I was wondering if there are alternative methods without having to import opencv.

I have also tried implementing a button widget that interrupts the loop, as such:

```
from ipywidgets import widgets 
import time
%pylab inline

button = widgets.Button(description='Press to stop')
display(button)

class Mode():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value='running'

mode=Mode()

def on_button_clicked(b):
    mode.value='stopped'

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    if mode.value=='stopped':
        break
```

But I see that the loop basically ignores the button presses.

Comment: For reference, the reason this doesn't work is that the kernel doesn't process the button click until after it's finished running the cell.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can trigger a `KeyboardInterrupt` in a Notebook via the menu "Kernel --> Interrupt".

So use this:

```
try:
    while True:
        do_something()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180941/how-to-kill-a-while-loop-with-a-keystroke) and click this menu entry.

Comment: `KeyboardInterrupt` is how the stop button works, though.

Answer (score 0):

### We need to explicitly poll the UI events

There's a neat little library called [jupyter-ui-poll](https://github.com/Kirill888/jupyter-ui-poll) which handles exactly this use case! The rest of the button setup you have can stay the same. We just need to wrap a pollable scope around the loop like so:

```py
from jupyter_ui_poll import ui_events
...
with ui_events() as poll:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        poll(10) # poll queued UI events including button
        if mode.value=='stopped':
            break
```

---

The issue is that the IPython kernel executes a queue of events, but there's one queue for both UI event callbacks and cell execution. So once it's busy working on a cell, UI events don't get processed. `jupyter-ui-poll` temporarily (inside the scope) adjusts this queueing behaviour to allow for explicit polling.