# try / except loop with bash terminal command as interrupt

Tags: python, gnu-screen

I'm using a simple python.py script in Linux. I need to run a while/counter loop and would like to stop the loop immediately by using a/any terminal command. I need to run the script using Screen. Simply stopping the Screen session doesn't work - it only stops the current process in the loop and then continues with the next process. The terminal command must preferably be specific for the loop in question.

I was looking at a Try / Except loop:

```
x = 1
y = 100
try:
    while x < y:
        process x
        time.sleep(10)
        x = x + 1
except ?
```

I don't know where to start. I need help with the implementation or maybe a better way to do this.

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180941/how-to-kill-a-while-loop-with-a-keystroke)?

Comment: Almost. I get the idea with the Keyboard Interrupt, but the script is actually triggered from php through ssh2_exec. I was hoping to be able to use exec or ssh2_exec to terminate the script/loop as well.

Comment: Is it possible to inserting a letter instead?

Comment: @Murillio4 Did some reading up. I trigger the puthon.py through a Screen command to run in the background. With screen I have the ability to insert a letter yes (through 'stuff'). I don't know if it is going to work though. What do you have in mind?

Comment: If it's possible o break the loop with user input, that would be the easiest solution. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1514035

Comment: @Murillio4 I've been trying to overcome this problem for ages. Your help made me think a bit and I managed to bypass the try/except loop by just adding an 'and condition' to the while loop. I then kill process x and change the 'and condition' with a little Bash script (which can be accessed through the terminal. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If this is linux then you can use Operating System Signals.
Just create a signal handler that throws an exception and catch that exception.
Register the signal handler with

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
```

This will register the handler function to be called when ever the SIGINT is sent to the process ID.

```
import signal, time
class InterruptException(Exception):
    pass

def handler(signum, frame):
    raise InterruptException("Recieved SIGINT")


# Set the signal handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

x = 1
y = 100
try:
    while x < y:
        print x
        time.sleep(10)
        x = x + 1
except InterruptException:
    print "Iterrupted"
```

From bash you can use

```
kill -2 PID
```

where PID is the process ID for the running script

You could always launch and kill from bash like

```
python my.app &
MY_PID=$!
kill -2 $MY_ID
```