# How do you check for user input without using input in Python

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to make it so that the while loop stops when you press c without stopping it using input.

The code I have at the moment is this:

```
    while True:
        print("Test")
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            if (msvcrt.getch() == "c"):
                os._exit(0)
                break
            elif (msvcrt.getch() != "c"):
                continue
```

FYI I am on windows.
Any ideas on how to do it besides the attempt I have already done?

Comment: did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180941/how-to-kill-a-while-loop-with-a-keystroke

Comment: I assume you're on Python 3 since you're using `print` as a function. In this case `msvcrt.getch()` returns `bytes`, and `b"c" != "c"`. You want `msvcrt.getwch()` to get a Unicode character that Python 3 returns as `str`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line `if (msvcrt.getch() == "c"):`.

You don't use `getch() == "c"` but `getch() == 99` or but `getch() == ord("c")`.

Why? Because it's what [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) returns. It returns an integer representing the Unicode code point of the only character in the string, in this case c.

---

By the way, Python already has `KeyboardInterrupt` that allows using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for interrupting code. You can also `try-except` it.

---

**Note**: You may also want to use 67 for if <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is on.