# Create our own signal to interrupt a Python program

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I have been searching through the Internet about how to create your own signal to interrupt a program. My aim is to press the letter R in my keyboard to interrupt a Python script but it seems that it is nearly impossible to create your own signal. Could anyone give me a piece of advice about where I should start?

Comment: maybe this: https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

Comment: this could also help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25442391/5649962

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python) answer could be helpful.