# While Loop No Longer Updating Data when added "Press Enter to Exit"

Tags: python

I am a beginner to Python and recently was making a **Discord Rich Prescense** application. The problem is that I was using a While Loop and added a "*Press Enter to Exit*" feature. This made the Rich Prescense stuck on One Quote. I have attached a screenshot of the problem.

```py
from config import credentials
from data import quotes
from pypresence import Presence
import random
import time

def quotegen():
    RPC = Presence(credentials.clientid)
    RPC.connect()

    while True:
        RPC.update(details="Random Quote:", state=random.choice(quotes.quotes))
        i = input("Press Enter to Exit")
        time.sleep(30)
        if not i:
            break
```

Screenshot of what its supposed to do:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You should post the code in the question as text.

Comment: `input` waits until it gets input. So it pauses your loop until it does. (This is a comment because I can't answer right now how you'd best actually do what you want)

Comment: what can i use then?

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13181036/2550406) help?

Comment: It's still not clear what "the problem" is. What should the code do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the keyboard module (https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/)
you can do it all.

I modified your code to fit your requirements:

```
import keyboard  # using module keyboard
from config import credentials
from data import quotes
from pypresence import Presence
import random
import time

def quotegen():
    RPC = Presence(credentials.clientid)
    RPC.connect()

    while True:
        RPC.update(details="Random Quote:", state=random.choice(quotes.quotes))
        i = input("Press Enter to Exit")
        time.sleep(30)
        if keyboard.is_pressed('enter'):  # if key 'enter' is pressed 
            break
```