# Press "Z" key to continue

Tags: python, input, key, keyboard-shortcuts, user-input

I'm making a text based game and I want to have the <kbd>Z</kbd> key pressed between two different pieces of dialogue. Does anyone know the code I would need to write in order to make the script carry on if the <kbd>Z</kbd> key is pressed?

Here is the general idea:

```
Dialogue 1
```

Code only advances if <kbd>Z</kbd> is pressed.

```
Dialogue 2
```

It would be helpful if someone could give me the code required to do this as I am still very inexperienced. I have tried looking it up and can't find anything that works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Thanks for the info and the code, I'll bear that in mind next time I post ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without resorting to CTypes or external libraries, you can check input like this:

```
def press_Z():
    while True:
        user_input = raw_input("Type Z to continue: ")
        if user_input == "Z":
            break

print "Dialogue 1"
press_Z()
print "Dialogue 2"
```

**Example of use:**

```
>>> 
Dialogue 1
Type Z to continue: Z  # I pressed Z then Enter
Dialogue 2
```

Consult [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694296/detect-in-python-which-keys-are-pressed) for information about getting keyboard strokes.