# How to print "yes" when written "y" in "Are you sure for exit" question?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print "yes" when the user writes "y" and print"no" when the user writes "n" in "Are you sure for the exit" question.
And the second problem is; if I write any letter instead of "y" or "n", the code is still running. How to fix it?

```
residuary = 1000

while True:

    operation = input("Select operation: ")

    if(operation == "q"):
        print("Are you sure for exit? (y/n)")
        answer = input("Answer:")
        y = "yes"
        n = "no"
        if(answer == "y"):
            print("See you again ")
            break
        else:
            continue
    elif(operation== "1"):
        print("Residuary is ${} .".format(residuary))
    elif (operation== "2"):
        amount = int(input("Amount you want to invest: "))
        residuary += amount
        print("${} sent to account.".format(amount))
        print("Available Residuary ${} ".format(residuary))
    elif (operation == "3"):
        amount = int(input("Amount you want to withdraw: "))
        if(amount > residuary):
                print("You can not withdraw more than available residuary!")
                continue
        residuary -= amount
        print("${} taken from account.".format(amount))
        print("Available Resiaduary ${} ".format(residuary))
    else:
        print("Invalid Operation!")
```

Comment: You can solve the "still running" problem with [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Comment: Your problem statement seems unclear, and as per your second problem your input is represented in the form of string so it will accept 1 as "1" and will keep on running until proper constraints are established in your code.

Comment: To print "yes" as soon as the user types "y" requires getting individual keystrokes as they are typed, which is OS dependent. There are some third-party modules out there that allow this, see [Detect in python which keys are pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694296/detect-in-python-which-keys-are-pressed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. You say **I want to print "yes" when the user writes "y" and print"no" when the user writes "n" in "Are you sure for the exit" question.** but this line would have printed by the time you collect user wish using input("Answer:") statement.

Are you after something like following code snippet?

```
if(operation == "q"):
    quit = False
    while(True):
        print("Are you sure you want to exit? ([y]es/[n]o)")
        answer = input("Answer:")
        if(answer.lower() == 'y': #You may check startswith() as well
            quit = True
            print('You chose yes')
            break
        elif(answer.lower() == 'n':
            print('You chose no')
            break
    if quit:
        print("See you again ")
        break
else:
    continue
```

Comment: Now I got my answer, thank you for it. But I've just started to learn Python and I am at the beginning now... I haven't learned the ".lower" So you say there is no way other than this, right?

Answer (score -1):

You just can add print statement under the condition of the printing:

```
    if(answer == "y"):
        print(y)
        print("See you again ")
        break
    elif (answer == "n"):
        print(n)
        continue
    else:
        break
```

adding else: break will exit the loop in case of the insertion of any other inout rather than y and n.

Comment: Answer:y ( I want to print yes here, not y)
yes
See you again

Comment: You have defined a variables called y which holds 'yes' as a string. Kindly, eview your code again.