# A function callback every time a key is pressed (regardless of which window has focus)?

Tags: python, linux, keypress, xorg, keylogger

I want to write a programme (in python) on Linux (Ubuntu Linux 9.10) that will keep track of how many key presses per second/minute I make. This includes normal letter keys, and control/shift/space/etc.

Is there some way to hook into X so that I can say "when a key is pressed call this function?". Since I want to have this running in the background while I work normally, this function call will have to be able to be aware of all key presses for all programmes. I suppose it's a bit like a keylogger.

This is only a personal thing, so I don't care about making it work on Windows/OSX, and I don't care about when people have fancy remote X sessions etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at what others have done already. You can take a look on how this [pykeylogger](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pykeylogger/develop) code handles Linux in its [backend](http://pykeylogger.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=pykeylogger/pykeylogger;a=blob_plain;f=pyxhook.py;hb=HEAD), and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend that you look at the StackOverflow question: [Is there a cross-platform python low-level API to capture or generate keyboard events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676713/is-there-a-cross-platform-python-low-level-api-to-capture-or-generate-keyboard-ev)

You could also look at the [Simple Python Keylogger](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pykeylogger/).

While not written in Python, you could also look at the [LKL Linux KeyLogger](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lkl/). WEB-NES-BAY has [instructions for using the LKL Linux KeyLogger](http://webnesbay.com/linux-keylogger-in-ubuntu/).