# Linux - Any way to get global KeyPresses without xlib's RECORD? (DBus/HAL/etc?)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keypress

[I was looking at how to capture global kepresses on Ubuntu Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901850/python-linux-a-function-callback-every-time-a-key-is-pressed-regardless-of-whi) regardless of what window has focus. And people suggested some programmes to look at. But they all use the RECORD thing in XLib, which [is broken in Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/xorg-server/+bug/315456). Is there some other way to capture all the keypresses on Ubuntu? How about using HAL? DBus?

Comment: Wait for or help upstream fix https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20500 -- then you'll have a working RECORD again.

Answer (score 3):

You can open the `/dev/input/eventN` device corresponding to the keyboard(s) and read the keyboard events from there.  You'll even get keyboard events from the non-X consoles.  This is the "evdev" interface.

From `Documentation/input/input.txt` in the kernel source:

> You can use blocking and nonblocking
>   reads, also `select()` on the
>   `/dev/input/eventX` devices, and you'll
>   always get a whole number of input
>   events on a read. Their layout is:

```
struct input_event {
    struct timeval time;
    unsigned short type;
    unsigned short code;
    unsigned int value;
};
```

> `time` is the timestamp, it returns
>   the time at which the event happened.
>   Type is for example `EV_REL` for
>   relative moment, `REL_KEY` for a
>   keypress or release. More types are
>   defined in `include/linux/input.h`.
>
> `code` is event code, for example
>   `REL_X` or `KEY_BACKSPACE`, again a
>   complete list is in
>   `include/linux/input.h`.
>
> `value` is the value the event
>   carries. Either a relative change for
>   `EV_REL`, absolute new value for `EV_ABS`
>   (joysticks ...), or 0 for `EV_KEY` for
>   release, 1 for keypress and 2 for
>   autorepeat.

Comment: IMHO, this is not a safe idea. If you application is started on a remote display, this way you will monitor the keyboard of the wrong machine. You should not bypass Xlib this way.

Comment: At the moment I don't care about remote displays or anything fancy like that

Comment: That's worth pointing out, but the OP specifically asked to bypass Xlib (and gave the examples of "DBus" and "HAL" which, while not actually being useable for the question, have nothing to do with Xlib).