# How to fix this script so that it won't peg the CPU?

Tags: python, performance, keyboard, cpu, xlib

On my home Kubuntu machine, I am running a script to beep on every keypress, no matter which window or application has focus, adapted from [this insightful page](http://rants.sayanriju.co.cc/script-to-make-tick-tick-sound-on-keypress)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

from Xlib.display import Display
import os
import sys

ZERO=[]
for i in range(0,32):
        ZERO.append(0)
ignorelist=[ZERO]

def main():    
        if os.getuid()==0:
                os.system("modprobe pcspkr")
                print("Speaker enabled, start as normal user")
                sys.exit()

        print("If no beep is heard, then run as root to enable pcspkr")

        disp = Display()
        while 1:
                keymap=disp.query_keymap()
                if keymap not in ignorelist:
                        os.system("beep")

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

The script works great, but it pegs both CPUs of my dual-core Intel machine at around 80% each, so I can do little else with the machine. How can I reduce the CPU requirements of this simple script without interfering with its operation? In other words, it should still beep at the moment of keypress, no matter what window or application has focus.

If this is not possible in Python, what other technologies should I look at? C? I would assume that there exists some kernel component which notifies applications of keypresses: how else does KDE handle global shortcuts? How can I get my application to receive these notices as well?

**The goal is to make a beep at the moment each key is pressed**, as I am training my fingers to type on a mechanical keyboard without bottoming out yet without missing keypresses. I just graduated from Cherry Browns to Cherry Blues and the lack of tactical feedback takes some time to get used to.

**Note that any solution must emit a beep no matter which window has focus. This program is intended to be used as a daemon that will run in the background of all applications that I use.**

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked to see what programs are pegging the CPU? It seems doubtful that a single threaded program such as this could be responsible by itself.

Comment: Yes, I have checked and killing this script removes the CPU load. Restarting it creates the CPU load again. Interestingly, repeatedly pressing a key to beep actually reduces the load.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start your script using nice. The nice command will lower the priority of your script, so that it will only run when the system has nothing else to do. That way it will still eat CPU cycles, but you will be able to use your system normally for other tasks.

See the man page for details.

**EDIT:**

To reduce CPU usage, you could add a small delay, using time.sleep(0.01). This will reduce the CPU load, but will marginally increase the time between the keypress and the resulting beep.

Comment: Thanks. Starting the app with `nice -n 19` does still peg the CPU but the system is more responsive at least.  This approach has a drawback of still keeping the CPU monitor pegged, so it becomes useless for determining unrelated system loads. Furthermore, the temp stays very high with the CPU this active. So this is a good workaround, but I really need something that addresses the root issue.

Comment: Lanaru's first suggestion was to add a small sleep delay. If you use time.sleep(0.05) you will at most a 50ms delay between your your keypress and yout beep. This will reduce the CPU load a lot.

Comment: Thanks, reviewing that even a delay of 0.01 reduces the CPU use significantly without affecting the operation.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm eager to learn what was wrong with my answer?

Comment: I upvoted, I sometimes never understand why some questions get downvotes without explanations. In fact, I would like to see SO punish downvotes with no comment.

Comment: The nice is solution only for CPU-bound processes to not destroy interactivity. A sleep is never a real solution either as it would only make the code miss presses. This is an IO-bound process; the original code uses the wrong X11 call that just queries the keyboard status, the real solution is to use a blocking call instead.

Comment: Thank you Antti. Which blocking call might that be, or where might I find it?

Comment: This was a hard call, there were some terrific answers here. I really learned from them all. In the end, the best compromise seems to be a small 0.01 delay in the while loop, and a generous helping of `nice`. This makes for an application that uses less resources, and gives up the resources that it does use when other applications need it, but still provides real-time keypress notifications in all applications. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Use events:

```
import Xlib
from Xlib.display import Display

display = Display()

screen = display.screen()
w = screen.root.create_window(0, 0, 100, 100, 1,
              screen.root_depth,
              event_mask = Xlib.X.KeyPressMask)
w.map()

while True:
    event = display.next_event()
    if event.type != Xlib.X.KeyPress:
        continue
    print "OHAI"
```

Details cadged from http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/doc/html/python-xlib_10.html#SEC9

Comment: Thank you. Having simply replaced `if keycode_requires_beep(event.detail)` with `else:` and replaced `# beep` with `os.system("beep")`, the script runs and does not peg the CPU, but it does not beep on keypresses. I would have expected to many beeps since I'm using simple `else` but not no beeps! Have you any idea why this may be?

Comment: No idea, but there's some questions you can find answers to in order to find out. 1: Are you getting in to that beep section, and just not hearing a beep when you get there? 2: are you getting an event when you hit a key? 3: what is the type of that event? All these questions are pretty standard debugging, when you know that what you expect to have happening isn't what you're seeing. The idea is to continually ask "what is actually happening?" and "What do I expect to happen?" until you find where your expectation and the vicious reality of broken code aren't lining up.

Comment: Thanks. I see that `print("1")` before the line `event = Display.next_event()` gets printed, but `print("2")` after that line does not. It seems to be hanging on that line.

Comment: Well, that got hairy real fast. The reason for your problem was right there in the docs: "To avoid flooding the clients with events in which they have no interest, they must explicitly tell the server which events they are interested in." You do that when you create a window, which means we need to create a window. I've replaced the example code with one that does this (and that I've actually tested). The two changes are the prelude that grabs the display and creates the window, and a correction to the comparison to check the type of the events.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this method only works when the new window is focused. Obviously this will not help me in everyday usage. I don't see anything other than `screen` which might be appropriate. Are there any other options? This would otherwise be a good solution. In any case I learned much from this post. Thanks.

Comment: Hm. I don't know. screen.root is a window, and you might be able to call change_attributes(event_mask = Xlib.X.KeyPressMask) on it, but you still wouldn't own the window, so I don't know if you'd get the events or not. http://lwn.net/Articles/101475/ does a screen.root.query_tree(), calls child.select_input(Xlib.X.KeyPressMask) on each child, then recurses. If you speak C, it would be but a small change to that code to get to where you want to be.

Answer (score 8):

Your while loop is consuming all your CPU's cycles since it's executing as fast as possible. You could add a small sleep() delay, but you risk missing out on some key events. Alternatively, consider using the [pyhook](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=Main_Page) module to monitor key presses.

Comment: Thank you. I am actually using Kubuntu Linux, not Windows. Nice find, though.

Answer (score 5):

Your program is hogging CPU because it is running an infinite loop that will keep your CPU busy with checking the keyboard status every millisecond or so, even if no keys are pressed. Since your computer has no indication that it can stop, it will keep on checking as often as possible, thereby burning resources.

As Iain suggested, the most elegant solution to this problem is to use `Display.next_event()`, which will tell the program to wait until a new event (e.g. a keypress) is received. During this waiting time, your program will not consume significant amounts of CPU and your load should go down dramatically.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the `Display.next_event()` seems to require its own window, and only functions for keypresses inside that window. I need a global solution.

Answer (score 4):

Working from [this answer to a previously posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1901928/462117), reveals [a Python module called `pyxhook`](http://pykeylogger.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=pykeylogger/pykeylogger;a=blob%5Fplain;f=pyxhook.py;hb=HEAD) that is part of [a program called pykeylogger](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pykeylogger/develop).

Using this `pyxhook` module, you should be able to beep on each keypress with the following code:

```
import pyxhook
import time
import os
import sys

def do_beep(event):
    os.system('beep')

hm = pyxhook.HookManager()
hm.HookKeyboard()
hm.KeyDown = do_beep
hm.start()
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(10)
    except: 
        break
hm.cancel()
```

I can't properly test it because I don't have a `beep` command. It does, however, report `sh: beep: command not found` for each keypress.

Comment: Thank you for finding the Linux version of pyhook! This solution is much more reasonable with the CPU, but it queues beep commands that are run too fast, so it is not suitable for real-time typing indication.

Comment: You could try `os.system('beep&')` to run each beep in the background, although I'm not sure how they will interact with each other. In addition, some versions of the beep command also allow customization of the beep sound -- for example, reducing the duration.

Comment: That is a good idea. In fact, I have tried to change the beep sound but [Kubuntu doesn't seem to acknowledge the change](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187338/system-bell-ignoring-preferences).

Comment: You seem to be changing the X11 bell settings, and then using the `beep` command to trigger the bell. I think the `beep` command interfaces with the PC speaker directly, and so is likely ignoring your X11 bell settings entirely. Try using [the options of the `beep` command itself](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/beep.1.html). The man page for `beep` has several examples, such as `beep -f 400 -l 10`. Note also that `beep` has `-s` and `-c` options, which you can use to avoid starting a new `beep` process for *every single* key press. This may also help (slightly) with delay.

Comment: Thank you nandhp! It did not even occur to me to use beep flags.