# wxPython TaskBarIcon key binding

Tags: python, wxpython

Is it possible to have a TaskBarIcon class constantly checking for key presses? So I have an icon in the taskbar, and it's waiting for the user to press say, Alt+S, once they do it triggers a function?

Answer (score 0):

No. The TaskBarIcon only detects mouse events. You would have to hook into the OS itself somehow to catch key presses. On Windows, you would use something like the PyWin32 package. See also the following answers from StackOverflow:

- [Is there a cross-platform python low-level API to capture or generate keyboard events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676713/is-there-a-cross-platform-python-low-level-api-to-capture-or-generate-keyboard-e)
- [Detect in python which keys are pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694296/detect-in-python-which-keys-are-pressed)

The second link mentions the [PyKeyLogger project](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pykeylogger/index.php?title=Main_Page) which might work for you. However, it only supports Windows and Linux.