# how do i get keystrokes outside of program and of arrow keys, backspace, enter, etc in python?

Tags: python, keyboard

so Im trying to write a program that needs to log keystrokes.  I have this current script:

```
def __call__(self):
    ch=msvcrt.getch()
    if ch in b'\x00\xe0':
        ch=msvcrt.getch()
    return ch
```

this works for basic keys but does not show arrowkeys, backspace, enter.  it also does not work outside of the program window.  how would i make it run outside of the window and log these other keys on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [pyHook](https://sourceforge.net/p/pyhook/wiki/PyHook_Tutorial/) and following one of the demos they have. It is an external library that you can use that allows you to monitor global keyboard and mouse events.

Comment: This seems to be Windows specific.  What OS are you working with @Jleong

Comment: I use Windows personally. I think this may be duplicate question, check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676713/is-there-a-cross-platform-python-low-level-api-to-capture-or-generate-keyboard-e)

Comment: @agardler do you know if there is any documentation for pyHook?  I do not understand the entire example that pyHook provided.  However for now implementing it in my code seems to be working with a few modifications to the parts I do understand

Comment: @J leong [this](http://pyhook.sourceforge.net/doc_1.5.0/) is what I found in terms of keyboard stroke documentation