# How does software like Spy++ get the information?

Tags: windows, winapi, desktop

I'm working on a software for test automation. To get it working it need's to "have a look" on the desktop and all open windows. It needs to know which windows are open and what controls they consist of. So it has to do something similar to what Spy++ is doing (Spy++ from Visual Studio).
Does anyone know how Spy ++ get's all the information?
Are there any Windows Methods one can call to retrieve information about open windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497.aspx) to get all top level windows. Within the `lpEnumFunc` you can call [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500(VS.85).aspx) to get child windows/controls of each top level window and then any other interesting function that gives you information you need, e.g. [GetClassName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633582(VS.85).aspx), [GetClassInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633578(VS.85).aspx), [GetClientRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633503(VS.85).aspx) etc. etc. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632595(VS.85).aspx) for more

Answer (score 4):

It's called a [windows hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997537.aspx).  Checkout the Win32 API [SetWindowHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990.aspx).

There are different types of hooks, they reside in a DLL and that DLL function is called by Windows for the type of windows messages of a specific thread or all threads in the same desktop.

Please also see my [related answer on Windows hooks here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310576/low-level-keyboard-input-on-windows/310602#310602).